# Unable to pass date in django URL

Tags: django, url, date

I am trying to pass date in yyyy/mm/dd format. Its accepting up to month only that is yyyy/mm.  When I pass date it says Page not found (404). something like in url weeklyreports/2011/03/22.

**Here is my url.py**

```
url(r'^weeklyreports/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d+)/$', 'weeklyreports'),
```

I have tried the below url also

```
url(r'^weeklyreports/\d{4}/\d{02}/\d{04}/$', 'weeklyreports'),
```

**My view weeklyreports.py**

```
def weeklyreports(request, year = None, month = None, day = None):
   today = datetime.date.today()
   if year:
      year = int(year)
      month = int(month)
      day = int(day)
      today = datetime.date(year, month, day)    

   weekday = today.weekday()
   start_delta = datetime.timedelta(days = weekday)
   start_of_week = today - start_delta

   week_dates = [start_of_week + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(7)]
   previous_week = start_of_week - datetime.timedelta(7)
   next_week = start_of_week + datetime.timedelta(7)
   return render_to_response('template/weeklyreports.html', locals(),
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**Here is my Template**

```
enter code here
<a href="/myapp/weeklyreports/{{previous_week|date:"Y/m/d"}}"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/img/previous.png"></a>
<b>Weekly Reports</b>
<a href="/myapp/weeklyreports/{{next_week|date:"Y/m/d"}}"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/img/next.png"></a>
```

Whats wrong in this code? Thanks in advance

Comment: does the pattern r'^weeklyreports/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/$' accept the url : weeklyreports/2010/1/1/  Because if not then something else might be wrong not shown in your code.

Comment: please post the entire urlconf

Comment: Could it have to do with the trailing slash? See [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#append-slash) and [here](http://morethanseven.net/2009/02/10/append-slashes-urls-django.html).

Answer (score 4):

Add a name to your url:

```
url(r'^weeklyreports/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d+)/$', 'weeklyreports', name='weeklyreports'),
```

In your template, use your named url `weeklyreports`:

```
<a href="{% url weeklyreports 2011 03 22 %}">
```

Does the above work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> Its accepting up to month only that is
>   yyyy/mm

these links:

```
<a href="/myapp/weeklyreports/{{previous_week|date:"Y/m/d"}}">
<a href="/myapp/weeklyreports/{{next_week|date:"Y/m/d"}}">
```

should be:

```
<a href="/myapp/weeklyreports/{{previous_week|date:"Y/m/d"}}/">
<a href="/myapp/weeklyreports/{{next_week|date:"Y/m/d"}}/">
```

Notice the trailing slash

> **What the URLconf searches against**
>
> The URLconf searches against the
>   requested URL, as a normal Python
>   string. This does not include GET or
>   POST parameters, or the domain name.
>
> For example, in a request to
>   http://www.example.com/myapp/, the
>   URLconf will look for myapp/.
>
> In a request to
>   http://www.example.com/myapp/?page=3,
>   the URLconf will look for myapp/.
>
> The URLconf doesn't look at the
>   request method. In other words, all
>   request methods -- POST, GET, HEAD,
>   etc. -- will be routed to the same
>   function for the same URL.

[`http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example)